# android studio 2.3.2, Instant run filling my password field value in email field on login page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sharedpreferences, android-studio-2.3

In the login page, email and password I am saving in SharedPreferences. After saving, when I am running full build then email and password are coming correctly, but when I am running instant run on the login page, then android automatic filling my password value in the email field. 
*My sample code is :*

**for saving :**

```
email = emailText.getText().toString();
passCode = passCodeText.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences.Editor sEditor = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_PAGE", 
        0).edit();
             sEditor.putString("emailLogin", email);
             sEditor.putString("passwordLogin", passCode);
             sEditor.apply();
```

**for restoring:**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_PAGE", 0);
        String mEmail = preferences.getString("emailLogin", null);
        String mPwd = preferences.getString("passwordLogin", null);
        if (mEmail != (null)) {
            emailText.setText(mEmail);
            passCodeText.setText(mPwd);
        }
```

Comment: Then what is an issue?

Comment: why instant run is not working properly, any setting problem in my android studio.. or it is an android studio bug?

Comment: We need more info about saving. Add code where `email` and `passCode` come from. ***///*** You're *saving plain text password* to hard drive? What kind of security is this?

Comment: email and passcode is EditText, I updated my question, u can check @Eugen Pechanec

Comment: @EugenPechanec what kind of security.... !! Sorry brother i didn't get u. Am i doing anything wrong? Could u please explain ?